# scala object modules is not a member of package play

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I'm trying to use mongo with Scala Play 2.5

I created a basic project from a template from the Play website. I'm now trying to create a class that imports the mongo module and I'm getting the following error:

`object modules is not a member of package play`

at this line:

`import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi`

I've enabled mongo in my `application.conf` like so:

`play.modules {
  enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
}`

and I've also added:

`libraryDependencies += "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.14"`

to build.sbt

Am I missing something?

Any ideas?

Why does it not find the "modules" package?

Comment: probably not relevant, but check if Play 2.5 is compatible with that particular version of reaactivemongo and with your used version of Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's the solution. Once the build config files are updated, you need to restart sbt. Otherwise it doesn't recognise the new dependencies.

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. It will help future readers if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with resolving relative imports. Do you have any other imports before
`import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi`?
Quick fix would be to use an absolute import:
`import _root_.play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi`

Comment: I think my issue was the same issue on my last stackoverflow post. I simply needed to restart sbt... 

I haven't seen this mentioned in the docs, but it does make sense when you think about it !